# Let $x$ be an independent variable. Does the differential dx depend on x?(from the definition of differential for variables & multivariable functions)

Tags: calculus, differential

I am studying differentiation of multivariable functions. Let's say we are considering the differential of $x$ on a point $x_0$. The book I'm studying with defines the differential of a variable as an arbitrarily small value non-dependent on $x$, but conventionally equal to $\Delta x$. But $\Delta x = x - x_0$ and thus it depends on $x$. What am I missing? Why can we say that $dx$ doesn't depend on $x$?

Comment: I think what the book is trying to say is that the value $x$ in itself does not matter but what matters is the change. Differentiability is a very local property.

Comment: Can you share your book author/title? Generally differential is linear function, dependent on function and point.

Comment: If it were possible, I would downvote the  book.

Comment: @zkutch it's a russian book Introduction to math analysis by V. A. Ilin, V. A. Sasovnichij, Bl. H. Sendov.

Comment: @MathsWizzard hmm that would make sense. In the end we are considering this when x tends to $x_0$, but if $x$ depended on a certain variable $t$, then the way $x$ would tend to $x_0$ depends on $t$.

Comment: I know this book. Which publisher year do you have?

Comment: @zkutch 1985. I know there are newer versions, but apparently those aren't available on the internet so I can't check.

Comment: Do you have in view pages 196-197?

Comment: @zkutch yes, I've seen those pages. In fact the differential is not defined as "independent from x" there. But in the chapters of multivariable functions it is defined so (page 476).

Comment: Ok. I am looking at that page. Can you formulate your question exactly? On page 476 there is not $\Delta x = x - x_0$. Only $\Delta x_i$.

Comment: @zkutch well, the book is still considering the differential on a point M. so $\Delta x_i$ can be seen as the difference between $x_i$ and the corresponding (i-th) coordinate of M.

Comment: From scratch we took $M(x_1, \cdots, x_m)$  and $f$. Then differential is defined by $(12.18)$, where $\Delta$'s are independent variables for differential. Only coefficients are dependent on $M$ and  $f$. Formulate, please, question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128076/discussion-between-h-a-y-k-and-zkutch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Zkutch, mine is just a misconception. I was falsely considering $\Delta x$ as dependent on $x$. Also, by claiming that $dx$ does not depend on $x$ it was meant that $\dfrac{d^2 x}{dx}=\dfrac{d\Delta x}{dx}=0$ which is true.